# How to access UIView in ViewController when calling function from another file?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

**Situation:** I paint stuff through a button-click on a subview. Then I add the subview to the view.

**Problem:** When calling `drawNew` from another swift file, the `if-loop` is not triggered. Probably because the `view` with the tag `777` does not get found.

**Question:** How do I tell the code to look for the `view` in ViewController?

**When do I call the function `drawNew()`?** I call it from another file with `override func touchesEnded(...)`

```
//###########################
//  ViewController.swift    
//###########################
var dv = Painting() // in here are functions to create a cg path

//
// IBActions
//
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
   // painting
    if sender.tag == 1 {
      drawNew()
    } else if sender.tag == 2 {
        CanvasView.clearCanvas()
    }

}

//
// FUNCTIONS
//
func drawNew() {
    dv.makeMeSomePath()
    if let foundView = view.viewWithTag(777) { // problem lies here maybe
        dv.tag = 111
        foundView.addSubview(dv)
        print("added subview")
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // prepare the canvas for
        let newView = CharacterView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                              y:0,
                                              width: HandwritingCanvasView.frame.width,
                                              height: HandwritingCanvasView.frame.height))

        newView.tag = 777
        HandwritingCanvasView.addSubview(newView)
//        self.view.addSubview(demoView)
    }
```

Then this is the other file from where I call the `drawNew()` func

```
//  HandwritingCanvasView.swift

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

     ViewController.drawNew()

}
```

Comment: Needs more details, When do you add the view with tag 777? and on what event you call drawNew() from another swift file?

Comment: @Gkolunia I added more code... Hope it helps...

Comment: And where do you set ViewController for HandwritingCanvasView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to have reference on newView in ViewController.

Try to do next

```
//###########################
//  ViewController.swift    
//###########################
weak var subView: UIView? //Add reference on your view

//
// FUNCTIONS
//
func drawNew() {
   dv.makeMeSomePath()
   if let foundView = subView { // Use the reference instead of searching view with tag
       dv.tag = 111
       foundView.addSubview(dv)
       print("added subview")
   }
 }


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Your code is here
    // ...
    HandwritingCanvasView.addSubview(newView)
    subView = newView
    //...
}
```

Comment: Works, thanks! I also needed to declare ``let mainViewController = ViewController()´´ in the HandwritingCanvas Class.. Above the class...